# AWS Step functions remove payload attribute from lambda output

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have a lambda that produces an array of json objects. I want the lambda result passed to a step function under a given attribute name.

Input to task that runs lambda:

```
{
"foo": "abc",
"bar": "def"
}
```

Output I want

```
{
"foo": "abc",
"bar": "def",
"lambdaOutput": [
  {...},
  {...}
]
}
```

I thought ResultSelector + ResultPath is supposed to solve this problem but I am stuck. I tried

```
"ResultSelector": {
        "lambdaOutput.$": "$.Payload",
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.lambdaOutput"
```

But this just creates a nested structure

```
{
"foo": "abc",
"bar": "def",
"lambdaOutput": 
    "lambdaOutput: {
    [ 
      {...},
      {...}
    ]
    }
}
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it from console, but from CDK, you can specify `payloadResponseOnly`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#payloadresponseonly

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not an Amazon States Language expert, but try just:

```
{
  ResultPath: "$.lambdaOutput"
}
```

Comment: That just inserts the payload inside of lambdaOutput. Anyway I found out that in CDK there is an option called payloadResponseOnly that solves this